# What is the format of specifying 'http' repositories in /etc/apt/sources.list?

Tags: ubuntu, debian, aptitude, apt, repository

After specifying the url of the repository, what do the tags like 'stable','non-free' mean in the entries of /etc/apt/sources.list ? If we know the url of a repository, how do we decide about these additional attributes while adding an entry in /etc/apt/sources.list ?

Answer (score 7):

Section 2.1 of the following [page](http://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/apt-howto/ch-basico.en.html) (reproduced below for ease of use) is what you want.

2.1 The /etc/apt/sources.list file
As part of its operation, APT uses a file that lists the 'sources' from which packages can be obtained. This file is /etc/apt/sources.list.

The entries in this file normally follow this format:

```
 deb http://host/debian distribution section1 section2 section3
 deb-src http://host/debian distribution section1 section2 section3
```

Of course, the above entries are fictitious and should not be used. The first word on each line, deb or deb-src, indicates the type of archive: whether it contains binary packages (deb), that is, the pre-compiled packages that we normally use, or source packages (deb-src), which are the original program sources plus the Debian control file (.dsc) and the diff.gz containing the changes needed for `debianizing' the program.

We usually find the following in the default Debian sources.list:

```
 # See sources.list(5) for more information, especially
 # Remember that you can only use http, ftp or file URIs
 # CDROMs are managed through the apt-cdrom tool.
 deb http://http.us.debian.org/debian stable main contrib non-free
 deb http://non-us.debian.org/debian-non-US stable/non-US main contrib non-free
 deb http://security.debian.org stable/updates main contrib non-free

 # Uncomment if you want the apt-get source function to work
 #deb-src http://http.us.debian.org/debian stable main contrib non-free
 #deb-src http://non-us.debian.org/debian-non-US stable/non-US main contrib non-free
```

These are the lines needed by a basic Debian install. The first deb line points to the official archive, the second to the non-US archive and the third to the archive of Debian security updates.

The two last lines are commented out (with a `#' in front), so apt-get will ignore them. These are deb-src lines, that is, they point to Debian source packages. If you often download program sources for testing or recompiling, uncomment them.

The /etc/apt/sources.list file can contain several types of lines. APT knows how to deal with archives of types http, ftp, file (local files, e.g., a directory containing a mounted ISO9660 filesystem) and ssh, that I know of.

Do not forget to run apt-get update after modifying the /etc/apt/sources.list file. You must do this to let APT obtain the package lists from the sources you specified.

Answer (score 1):

Each repository can decide how they wish to structure their packages.

Some provide "standard" naming, such as `stable`, `unstable` and `non-free`, but each can differ - adding `sarge`, `potato` and more.

One such provider can be seen on Opera's site, [here](http://deb.opera.com/). As you browse the directory strcuture, you can see how the `deb` directives match with the actual URL being used.

Answer (score 1):

If you know the URL of a repository you can lookup the `dists` sub-directory to find out all the distributions that are available in that repository. If you enter those directories you can find out a `Release` file that lists the available sections in a `Component` field.

Example with the official Debian repository: [http://ftp.debian.org/debian/](http://ftp.debian.org/debian)

The distributions available can be seen at: [http://ftp.debian.org/debian/dists/](http://ftp.debian.org/debian/dists)

If you take the lenny distributione you can grab the Release file here: http://ftp.debian.org/debian/dists/lenny/Release

Inside that file you can find the list of sections:

```
Components: main contrib non-free
```

And like people have already explained, in `/etc/apt/sources.lists` you have lines in the following format:

```
deb repository-url distribution section1 section2 section3
```

Now you can explore any well-maintained Debian repository !